# Setting up TLS encryption for ODBC based client

Tags: mysql, sql-server, db2, sqlanywhere

I am a newbie in database technologies.I am looking to secure all communications between my client and the various DB's.
My client supports various ODBC databases(sqlanywhere,sybase,HANA) and other enterprise databases like oracle,DB2,MS SqlServer,MySql.
I want to understand how can i set up the TLS encryption for these ?
Does setting up the data source for these with the encryption setup suffice,given i also configure the server with the certificate ?
My current client code simply calls the ODBC_connect API ?I think if the configuration works,i need not even change my code.Please help validating this ?

Comment: Way too broad of a question; need to reduce the scope to a particular RDMBS and the code/config you've tried for said RDBMS; highly doubtful one solution will work for all RDBMS products; from just a Sybase ASE perspective ... DBA has to setup dataserver to support ssl (to include getting a(n official) cert generated and installed, configuring additional listeners, and configuring the SSL cipher suite preferences)

Answer (score 0):

From a DB2 perspective: Current DB2-client versions allow encryption of ODBC and CLI connections via TLS. Current and older versions allow encryption of JDBC connections with TLS. The detailed instructions are in the DB2 Knowledge Centre. No need to change the application code, but configuration changes are required at client side and at server side.